# Adding Notifications On PCL project xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, cross-platform

I am trying to understand how notifications work on a pcl project. I followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/) tutorial but it refers most on android applications, not so muck on a pcl project. Can i implement notifications from the portable project? First i could use a button that pops a  local notification.

For now i am interested in the android implementation more than the ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins to display LocalNotification in XamarinForms PCL

For example [LocalNotificationsPlugin](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin)

API Usage

Call CrossLocalNotifications.Current from any project or PCL to gain access to APIs.

Display a local notification immediately

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body");
```

Display a local notification at a scheduled date/time

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body", 101, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
```

Cancel a local notification

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Cancel(101);
```

or

[Toasts.Forms.Plugin](https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin)

Usage

Use dependency service in order to resolve IToastNotificator.

```
var notificator = DependencyService.Get<IToastNotificator>();

var options = new NotificationOptions()
            {
                Title = "Title",
                Description = "Description"
            };

var result = await notificator.Notify(options);
```

The result that is returned is a NotificationResult with an Action inside with one of the following values.

```
[Flags]
public enum NotificationAction
{
    Timeout = 1, // Hides by itself
    Clicked = 2, // User clicked on notification
    Dismissed = 4, // User manually dismissed notification
    ApplicationHidden = 8, // Application went to background
    Failed = 16 // When failed to display the toast
}
```

If you want the Clicked NotificationAction you must set IsClickable = true in the NotificationOptions.

Another [aritchie/notifications](https://github.com/aritchie/notifications)

Send a notification

```
await CrossNotifications.Current.Send("My Title", "My message for the notification");
```

Send a scheduled notification:

```
await CrossNotifications.Current.Send("Happy Birthday", "I sent this a long time ago", when = TimeSpan.FromDays(50));
```

Get a list of scheduled notifications

```
var list = await CrossNotifications.Current.GetScheduledNotifications();
```

Cancel a specific notification

```
var id = await CrossNotifications.Current.Send("Hi", "This is my scheduled notification", when = TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
await CrossNotifications.Current.Cancel(id);
```

Cancel all scheduled notifications and clear badge:

```
CrossNotifications.Current.CancelAll();
```

To set a badge:

Setting badges works on all platforms, though only select flavours of Android. A 3rd party library is used to accomplish this.

```
await CrossNotifications.Current.SetBadge(4);
await CrossNotifications.Current.GetBadge();
```

// 0 clears badge

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: Is there a way to set a notification at an exact time? Like 20:35? I started using LocalNotificationsPlugin.